# Show first item and show/hide anothers when click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I want to show the first 5 `divs` with a `Show more` and `Show less` link enabling users to expand them. When Page loads I want only one div visible and rest hidden. On clicking `Show more` I want to show first five.

My divs are arranged like this:

```
<div class = "OffersContainer">
    <div class='pan-box'></div>
    <div class='pan-box'></div>
    <div class='pan-box'></div>
</div>
```

I want the effect on my divs inside the `OffersContainer`. How can I do this with jquery?

Comment: Do you want the first div to be visible at all times? Or just visible on page load and then bound to the effect of 'Show more/less'?

Comment: Yes I want the first div to be visible at all times and want to expand/collapse the rest divs(rest of the five divs) on show/less links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`:gt()`](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector to finding element that has index great than number.

```js
$(".OffersContainer > div:gt(0)").hide();
$(".OffersContainer > span").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings("div:gt(0)").slideToggle(); 
    $(this).text($(this).text() == "Show more" ? "Show less" : "Show more");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="OffersContainer">
    <div class='pan-box'>A</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>B</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>C</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>D</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>E</div>
    <span>Show more</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mohammad Nice solution. Lets say If I want to show first 3 divs upon clicking  show more for the first time and then upon clicking it second time, I want to show all divs. What change would i need to make in your suggested code?
Your help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @HumaAli You can use `:lt()` selector to finding element with less index, For example like this simple [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qo55rmuy/). If you problem doesn't solve by example ask question to finding better answer.

Comment: @Mohammad great it works! But how can I apply the `toggling` effect? I mean how can I close these expanded divs on `show less`?

Answer (score 1):

**Working Demo**

[JS FIDDLE](https://fiddle.jshell.net/nadeemmnn2007/wv6z25to/)

Code:

CSS

```
#more,#less,.hide{display:none;}
```

### HTML

```
<div class = "OffersContainer">
    <div class='pan-box'>1</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>2</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>3</div>

    <div class='pan-box'>4</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>5</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>6</div>

    <div class='pan-box'>7</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>8</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>9</div>

    <div class='pan-box'>a</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>b</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>c</div>
</div>
```

### JQUERY

```
$(function () {
    display();
    $('#more').on('click',function(){
        $(".pan-box").removeClass('hide');
        $(this).hide();
        $('#less').show();
    });
    $('#less').on('click',function(){
        display();
        $(this).hide();
        $('#more').show();
    });         
});

function display(){
    $(".pan-box").each(function (i,v) {
        if(i>=4){
            $(this).nextAll().addClass( "hide");
        }   
        $('#more').show();                       
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4jyn5796/)

You can use [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)  , [.slidedown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/)

```
 .OffersContainer{display:none;}

 <div class="trip">Show more</div>
<div class = "OffersContainer">
    <div class='pan-box'></div>
    <div class='pan-box'></div>
    <div class='pan-box'></div>
</div>

$(".trip").click(function(){

       if($(".OffersContainer").hasClass("visible")){

              $(".OffersContainer").slideUp().removeClass("visible");
              $(".trip").html("show more");
          }else
          {

             $(".OffersContainer").slideDown().addClass("visible");

             $(".trip").html("show less");
          }

});
```

Comment: @Multistack You should put your question properly first then , Now use the above code . Try on you own and paste on your question. So that it can be helpful for others to understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal way but working...

```js
$("#state").on("click", function(){
  $(".OffersContainer").toggle(function(){
    if($(this).is(":visible")){
      $("#state").text("Show less");
    }
    else  {
      //alert("no visible"); 
      $("#state").text("Show more");
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.OffersContainer{display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="state">Show more</div>
<div class = "OffersContainer">
    <div class='pan-box'>div1</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>div2</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>div3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When i click on every `.pan-box` make it hidden.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I've edited and make it clearer and easier